# Jekyll categories not working for the address link

Tags: jekyll

I learned from Jekyll that I can put a category tab in my markdown file. And the address of that post should be `homepage/category/filename`.

For example, if my markdown file has a `category:work`, and my post title is `hello-work`, my post link should be something like `localhost/work/hello-work`.

But somehow this trick does not work for me. I am still getting address like `localhost/post/hello-work`.

I also tried to create another folder structure like `work/_posts/hello-work.md`, it also does not work for me. The email address is always `localhost/post/hello-work`.

Any idea about where possible goes wrong?

Comment: It depends on your [permalink configuration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), but for a default Jekyll instance created with `jekyll new`, adding `category: work` to the front matter works as expected, with the category becoming a part of the URL.

Comment: Can you show your directory and file structure?

Comment: I think you are right. I tried to change the permalink in my config file. But I found that only permalink: /:title/ works. Any other variables, such as permalink: /:category/:title, or permalink: /:tag/:title, are all not working. There is an error when I rebuild the project. But permalink: /:title/:title/ works.

Comment: permalink: /:categories/:title does work!

Comment: Yeah, if you check the [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/), `:category` isn't valid, and tags neither. That's also the main difference between tags and categories: categories can be part of the URL, and tags can't.